# How to implement longest-queue-first rule for traffic lights in SUMO or FLOW?

Tags: sumo, flow-project

How to implement longest-queue-first rule for traffic lights in SUMO or FLOW?

It seems SUMO only supports three kind of traffic light, which is not flexible enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMO has an in-built `actuated` traffic light algorithm which in conjunction with lane detectors, prolongs the green phase of the traffic light.

`Longest queue first` seems like a rule-based algorithm which can be easily implemented using `TraCI`. At the beginning of each phase, you could check the number of `waiting vehicles per edge` and set the green phase accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, acutally I want to try a rule-based algorithm to dynamically control the traffic light, such as observing the real-time waiting queue at every second, and simutaneously change traffic light to give priority to longest queue.

Comment: Could you share more details in how to implement rule-based algorithm using TraCI? Thank you!

Comment: @PaoRaw rule based algorithm, as the name suggests, can be implemented using basic `if...else` conditions. You can periodically check the `number of waiting vehicle per edge` and make your decisions accordingly. Each edge can be `subscribed` to and can be used to get the Vehicle IDs for the last time step. Which can in-turn be used to find if they are waiting or not

Comment: Hi @FrainBr33z3 , thanks for your explanation. I am trying to subscribe such a variable like "number of waiting vehicles per edge", but I can't locate it among the available options. Do you have any suggestions? I'm trying to subscribe all vehicles locations, but it is not efficient to do so.

Comment: When using SUMO to create a grid network, it seems we have to define route for different types of vehicles. The problem comes when we need a large grid network such as 10*10. It would be impossible to manually input the routes for different type of vehicles, especially when considering the turning flow at intersections. Can you provide some insights on this? Thank you!